# jQuery change selected value not working ( JSFiddle included )

Tags: html, mootools

http://jsfiddle.net/vAa9G/42/

I've included this fiddle which has two Jquery codes to change the select value.

```
$("#selectbox").val("3");

$("select option[value='3']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Both are not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: Select jQuery library and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/vAa9G/43/

Answer (score 3):

The example jsFiddle is using MooTools, not jQuery.
This is the updated version using jQuery. I just changed the library selection on the side menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/vAa9G/49/

The correct syntax to work with MooTools, in your case, is:

```
$('selectbox').set('value', '3');
```

Also jsFiddle available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vAa9G/52/